# Script to check if SSH service in Docker is up

Tags: bash, shell, docker, ssh, sh

My docker container has two services: a web service and a SSH server.

The SSH server is openssh-server and I need to run the command `docker exec -it my-container sudo service ssh restart` from outside the container to start the SSH server.

However, the command doesn't succeed all the time. Every time I need to manually check if the SSH server is up in the container using the command: `ssh root@localhost`:

1) If the SSH server fails to start, the result is `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

2) Otherwise, it asks for the password. (Which indicates that the SSH server is up)

Since I have to deploy multiple containers at the same time, it is unrealistic to check every container manually. Therefore, I want to retry the `docker exec -it my-container sudo service ssh restart` command automatically if the SSH serve fails to start. But I am not sure how to write the bash script to achieve this. It basically should work like this:

```
while (ssh_server_fails_to_start):
    docker exec -it my-container sudo service ssh restart
```

Any comments or ideas are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a pretty unusual setup: usually a Docker container runs only one service, it isn't ssh, and neither `sudo` nor `service` really work well in a Docker environment.  What's your actual goal with trying to start an sshd?  Could you accomplish it by using `sudo docker exec` from the host?

Comment: @DavidMaze I actually use `sudo docker exec` from to host to start the SSH service in a Docker container. I have installed the `sudo` in the container and I am sure that `sudo service ssh restart` works pretty well in the container. The problem is: the call of `docker exec -it my-container sudo service ssh restart` doesn't always succeed. That's why I want to retry the command if it fails.

Comment: If you can ssh to the host, and `sudo docker exec`, why do you need an ssh daemon running in the container (with its attendant access, security and management considerations)?

Comment: @DavidMaze I am using the container to simulate a host actually. It is a bad practice to runs multiple services in a container but I have to unfortunately. I just need to write a script the test the ssh connection to the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `sshd` is up an running, it will accept connections on its certain port.  Otherwise, the connection attempt will fail.

If you run the following command:

```
ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=No root@localhost true
```

This will fail in either way, but the output will be different.  In the case that the server is running and accepting connections, the explicit switch-off of password authentication will make it fail with this message:

```
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Otherwise it will print out a message like this:

```
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

So I propose to scan the error message for a hint like this:

```
if ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=No root@localhost true \
     |& grep -q "Connection refused"
then
    echo "No server reachable!"
else
    echo "Server reachable."
fi
```

So you could write your script like this:

```
while ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=No root@localhost true \
        |& grep -q "Connection refused"
do
  docker exec -it my-container sudo service ssh restart
done
```

You might want to add some sleep delays to avoid hurried restarts.  Maybe the ssh server just needs some time to accept connections after being restarted.

Answer (score -1):

To test the ssh connection, we can use `sshpass` package to provide a password in the command line.

```
while : ; do
    docker exec -it my-container sudo service ssh restart
    sleep 5s
    sshpass -p 'root' ssh -q root@localhost -p 2222 exit
    if [ $? == 0 ]; then
            echo "SSH server is running."
            break
    fi
    echo "SSH server is not running. Restarting..."
done
```

Comment: Urgs.  PW in source?  I propose to change this to using ssh keys.